# How to change filenames when merging pull requests

Tags: git, merge

I have to merge two pull requests A and B.
Both requests have paths with the same name but completely different content.
I can't make them change their pull requests.

One way I think this can be done is merge pr A normally and then fetch B on a new branch, change what I want, commit the changes and then merge the new branch onto master.

Does it make sense and if it does how can I do it?

Comment: What happens when B updates their content with the same path?  This is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: they wont, they don't have access to the repo any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the pull requests are single commits :

I think the "right" way to do this would be to fetch B's changes, checkout a new branch, change the filename and do a commit --amend.

This will make the most sense when you look at your repository's history as you won't have the same filename representing completely different content. Since B doesn't have access to the repo anymore it doesn't matter that you keep it consistent for them.

If for some reason the pull requests are more than one commit, you can do `git filter-branch` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) on B's commits and change the file's name for every commit in that branch's history.

Making a separate commit that just changes the filename will cause confusion if for some unknown reason you need to roll back to B's original commit. Also diff'ing between the branches will be very weird. Probably better to rewrite history to maintain consistency (again, since B's repo isn't an issue).